# How should I set up an awesome Static HTML Server?

Tags: ftp, redirect, static-content

### Background

I'm trying to setup a linux server (Ubuntu, open to suggestions) over ssh and I keep running into walls, Googling, moving a bit forward, and then running into another wall, then running into a big wall like an install/mysql/user creation (It's pretty bad to run as root all the time, right?) messing up somewhere, getting frustrated, wiping and starting over.

### What I Want

I'm still thinking this out, but eventually, I want a very secure/light/fast server to host static html (and maybe a Movable Type/Jekyll (static) blog?) at the root of my site: http://wiswanson.com (no-www philosophy, currently using S3 and a cname). I'm thinking I still want to host images and files on Amazon S3 (cdn.wiswanson.com cname? Redirect /img and /files with a mod_rewrite? What's better and why?), maybe eventually move that to Amazon Cloud Front. Ideally, this would somehow pull from Dropbox and post up the html when it's moved to a published folder. I'm very open to ideas and suggestions.

Are there any ssh/ftp/server setup tutorials or resources that are really solid & well written? Would this be better for Server Fault?

Comment: Wow, my head's spinning.  And why are you trying to complicate things so much with CDN, S3, Amazon Cloud Front, mod_rewrite, DropBox for what's obviously your first Web server setup.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest you start by setting up a local test server (virtual machines are great for this) and use that to learn what you need to know *before* putting it on the Internet.

From your question I get the impression that you've never done anything like this before and you therefore *will* make mistakes that will either render your system inoperable, inaccessible or just plain wide open to attack.

Concerning those issues you're having, pick one at a time and ask specific questions here. The SF community certainly has the expertise, as this is the stuff many make their living from.

Answer (score 1):

May I suggest **using AWS S3 directly** for the whole thing?

That way you only pay for what you use and don't have to manage anything.

AWS recently released the feature that allows this. (see
http://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2011/02/17/Amazon-S3-Website-Features/ )

Also, be sure to check the docs to see if it meets your specs:
http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/index.html?WebsiteHosting.html

Also, you can find several easy drag-and-drop S3 clients for Windows. I use CloudBerry free edition, but there are other good ones too.

Comment: S3 is what I'm doing right now, but it doesn't support no-www or mod_rewrite.

Answer (score 0):

If you are thinking about going to the cloud, then do it, but do it right. Why would you want to make your users connect to a server that get's the info partially from the cloud?

I sugest you put everything on an EC2-instance and use EBS or S3 as a storage solution. This will make everything lightening fast and a micro-instance falls within the free-tier.

If you encounter any problems setting up your LAMP-stack, come back to us with a specific problem.

Answer (score 0):

NodeJS with connect.  It is perfect for this type of thing.  It is evented, so it doesn't spawn a new thread for each connection, saving you resources and increasing total possible load.  You can have millions of connections with no noticeable lag. Here is some basic code:

```
var connect = require('connect'),
    doc_root = "/path/to/files",
    port = 8888;

connect(
    static(doc_root)
).listen(port);
```

Save this into a file. For example, `mycode.js`.

You will probably want to install npm, it's really convenient for adding packages in node.  Here are some links:

- [Installing node](https://github.com/joyent/node)
- [Installing npm (package manager)](https://github.com/isaacs/npm)
- `sudo npm install connect`- install the connect module.

When you get it installed, run your server with `node mycode.js`